# Есть ли в Java функции?

Tags: java, функции, классы, groovy

В питоне есть понятие функций и понятие классов с их методами (которые по сути функции).

Но читаю документацию Java, и не нахожу чтоб было что-то про создание функций. Есть про создание методов. Но метод в Java, как я понимаю это функция внутри класса? А просто голая функция бывает?

Спасибо.

Comment: в Java любая функция - часть какого то объекта.

Comment: То есть нельзя написать голую функцию, и вызывать её function()? Она обязательно должна быть внутри какого-то объекта. Кроме класса она может быть внутри какого-то объекта?

Comment: Она может быть внутри класса, как статическая функция. А может быть внутри экземпляра класса. Сама по себе она быть не может.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методы в Java - это поведение классов. Поэтому от классов они неотделимы. Есть статические и не статические методы. Для вызыва нестатических методов нужно создавать экземпляр класса(объект):

```
class Function {
    public String getLabel() {
        return "non-static method";
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function function = new Function();
        String label = function.getLabel();
    }
}
```

Для вызыва статических объект не нужен:

```
class Function {
    public static String getLabel() {
        return "static method";
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String label = Function.getLabel();
   }
}
```

Comment: То есть нельзя написать голую функцию, и вызывать её function(), только внутри какого-то класса и вызывать Class.function()?

Comment: @pleyades Именно

Comment: Выглядит как ограничение какое-то, не удобно. Или думаете дело привычки?

Comment: @pleyades это действительно ограничение, оно обусловленно тем, что java - ооп язык, и там по определению все сущности - объекты, у которых есть данные и поведение(способы работать с данными).

Comment: Ну а в груви то как? пришел из гугла сюда по запросу "groovy функции" передлайте вопрос, он не отвечет насчёт груви никак